# How to render multi-text part HTML label with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I need to render a label that has two parts, because some CSS is applied to both text parts differently (different colors & font).  The HTML output should look something like this:

```
<label for="lname1" class="required">
   <span class="field-name">Last name</span> 
<strong class="required">(required)</strong></label>
```

I've tried things like this without joy:

```
<label for="lname1" th:text="#{lastname}" class="required">Last Name
   <strong class="required"><span th:text="#{required}">(required)
</span></strong></label>
```

It seems the template engine ignores everything after the first ">" in the label tag.  Is there any way to achieve this short of faking it with two label tags for every form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "problem" your experiencing is the fact that the `th:text` replaces all child elements.

This should produce exactly what you want:

```xml
<label for="lname1" class="required">
   <span class="field-name" th:text="#{lastname}">Last name</span> 
<strong class="required" th:text="#{required}">(required)</strong></label>
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  Has the added benefit of still being able to work realistically in "prototyping mode".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expression Inlining to archive your goal:

```
<label for="lname1" class="required">
  [[${lastname}]]
  <strong class="required">
    <span th:text="#{required}">(required)</span>
  </strong>
</label>
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html Chapter 12: Inlining

Comment: Thanks, and now I know which version of Thymeleaf I'm using because it didn't work.  For some reason, the latest spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf (1.5.10.RELEASE) is pulling in Thymeleaf 2.1.6.RELEASE!  What the heck?

Comment: Does it work now? Were you able to update to a recent version? I thought that 2.1 already has the inline feature (found something like Text-Inlining in the documentation).

Comment: I having updated yet.  Perhaps there is another reason why Thymeleaf didn't process the `[[#{var}]]` and just let it output literally. I'd like to get this to work because it will come in useful for other areas of my application.

Comment: Sadly it seems Spring-boot hasn't been updated for compatibility with Thymeleaf 3.x. yet since I tried to override and Spring fails spectacularly when attempting to auto-configure Thymeleaf 3.0.9.RELEASE.   I also confirmed that the form of inlining you're referring to was released only in version 3:  https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/394